# JsonGenerationException when serializing nested object using custom serializer in Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

Here is the class that I want to serialize.

```
public class ItemRow<T> {

    private String id;
    private List<T> items;
}
```

There are two variations that are allowed.
    `ItemRow<String>, ItemRow<ItemRow>`. 
     In the latter case, it will be nested.

eg:

```
ItemRow item1 = new ItemRow("abc", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(item1);
System.out.println(result);
```

should give

```
{
     "abc":["item1","item2","item3"]
}
```

Now, the latter case

```
ItemRow item2 = new ItemRow("cde", Arrays.asList("item4, item5"));
ItemRow item = new ItemRow("combined", Arrays.asList(item1,item2));
result = mapper.writeValueAsString(item);
System.out.println(result);
```

should give

```
{
    "combined": {
        "abc": ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
        "cde": ["item4", "item5"]
    }
}
```

But I get exception while serializing the latter. The first one works as expected. so I believe the recursive serialization is failing, but I am unable to find out why

Here is exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:1961)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonGeneratorImpl._reportCantWriteValueExpectName(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._verifyValueWrite(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeStartObject(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:279)
    at hello.ItemRowSerializer.serialize(ItemRow.java:58)
    at hello.ItemRowSerializer.serialize(ItemRow.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:381)
    at hello.ItemRowSerializer.serialize(ItemRow.java:67)
    at hello.ItemRowSerializer.serialize(ItemRow.java:42)
```

Serializer implementation

```
class ItemRowSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ItemRow> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(ItemRow itemRow, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

        String id = itemRow.getId();
        List<Object> items = itemRow.getItems();

        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeFieldName(id);
            jgen.writeStartArray();
            jgen.writeEndArray();
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
        else {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            Object item = items.get(0);
            jgen.writeFieldName(id);
            if (item instanceof  ItemRow){
                for (Object i : items) {
                    //ItemRow temp = (ItemRow) i;
                    //jgen.writeObjectField(temp.getId(), temp);
                    //jgen.writeObjectField(id, i);
                    jgen.writeStartObject();
                    jgen.writeObject(i);
                    jgen.writeEndObject();
                }
            }
            else {
                //jgen.writeFieldName(id);
                jgen.writeStartArray();
                for (Object arg : items) {
                    jgen.writeString(arg.toString());
                }
                jgen.writeEndArray();
            }
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your serializer algoritihm is incorrect. The code is down above. You do not need to start object when you are directly deserializing an object. I removed this steps and minimized the code.

Example Test;

```
@Test
public void serializeTest() throws JsonProcessingException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(ItemRow.class, new ItemRowSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    ItemRow item1 = new ItemRow("abc", Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(item1);
    System.out.println(result);


    ItemRow item2 = new ItemRow("cde", Arrays.asList("item4", "item5"));


    ItemRow item6 = new ItemRow("deeper-1", Arrays.asList("item6", "item7"));
    ItemRow item7 = new ItemRow("deeper-2", Arrays.asList("item6", "item7"));
    ItemRow item8 = new ItemRow("deeper", Arrays.asList(item6, item7));

    ItemRow item3 = new ItemRow("inner-1", Arrays.asList("item6", "item7"));
    ItemRow item4 = new ItemRow("inner-2", Arrays.asList("item6", "item7"));
    ItemRow item5 = new ItemRow("inner", Arrays.asList(item3, item4, item8));




    ItemRow item = new ItemRow("combined", Arrays.asList(item1,item2,item5));
    result = mapper.writeValueAsString(item);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Algorithm;

```
public class ItemRowSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ItemRow>
{

    @Override
    public void serialize(ItemRow itemRow, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException
    {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        writeInnerObject(jgen, itemRow);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }


    private void writeStringArr(JsonGenerator jgen, List items) throws IOException
    {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (Object arg : items)
        {
            jgen.writeString(arg.toString());
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }


    private void writeInnerObject(JsonGenerator jgen, ItemRow row) throws IOException
    {
        jgen.writeFieldName(row.getId());

        if (row.getItems().size() > 0 && row.getItems().get(0) instanceof ItemRow)
        {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getItems().size(); i++)
            {
                ItemRow innerRow = (ItemRow) row.getItems().get(i);
                if( innerRow.getItems().size() > 0 && innerRow.getItems().get(0) instanceof ItemRow )
                {
                    writeInnerObject(jgen, innerRow);
                }
                else
                {
                    jgen.writeFieldName(innerRow.getId());
                    writeStringArr(jgen, innerRow.getItems());
                }
            }
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            writeStringArr(jgen, row.getItems());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output.  The output from this `{"combined":[{"abc":["item1","item2","item3"]},{"cde":["item4, item5"]}]}`. As you can see, it has list node to "combined" but I wanted an object node. see above in the question

Comment: @brainstorm The code is now working and i added more complex example.

Comment: +1 this seems right. I will do some testing and will accept the answer once I confirmed it works on different inputs. I have two other questions posted on jackson. if you get time, kindly see if you can help there!

Comment: I tried to write a deserializer and is not working when used in a map. can you give some input here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028149/unrecognizedpropertyexception-when-deserializing-a-map-using-custom-jackson-dese